# only 2 of 3 localizable strings (xxx) used

Tags: ios, localization, localizable.strings

in my app I use localization with base-localization. I have the Main.storyboard (Base), Main.storyboard (German), Main.storyboard (French) and Main.storyboard (English).

And for a part of the content to show I have Localizable-stings with Localizable.strings (Base), Localizable.strings (English), Localizable.strings (German) and Localizable.strings (French).

And I load XML-files which contains text in the 3 languages.

If the device has non of those languages english will be used.

If the device has en-EN, all is in english.

If the device has de-DE, all is in german.

If the device has fr-FR, the content of Main.storyboard (French) and the french texts of the XML are used, but not the content of the Localizable.strings (French). Instead the Localizable.strings (Base) is used.

I tested by replacing the complete content of the Localizable.strings (French) with the content of Localizable.strings (German) without success - so no error in the Localizable.strings (French)-file.

What can I do or how can I detect where I made a error?

[EDIT]
I checked "for fun" several iOS-Versions:

all languages will be correct displayed with iOS 8.1 - 8.4. When running with iOS 9.2 (Simulator and real device) the issue occurs. Is there any knowledge about this?

Answer (score 0):

Found my "logic-error".

The localization is made with base and 3 languages (english, french and german). Base = english. In the Targets -> Info I set the "Localization native development region" to France. Obviously this defines when the localizable.strings (Base) is used. In my case if device set to France/French the Base-localization (in english) was used. Changed the "Localization native development region" to English (UK) solved the problem.